# UKCEH Land Cover files missing the lyr file

Tags: arcgis-pro, united-kingdom, layer-file

I am trying to use the UKCEH Land Cover 2021 files to create a habitat map in ArcGIS Pro. On the supporting documents pdf it says to get the symbology to work visually, you need to use the accompanying .lyr file that came with the download. The issue is, there is no .lyr file in any of the downloads, only 2 QML files. Has anyone used these before and has the .lyr files, or at least knows what value equates to each habitat, as I cannot seem to find this information on their website at all.

Answer (score 1):

LCM layer files are available to download with the link at the very bottom of this page https://www.ceh.ac.uk/data/ukceh-land-cover-maps